# How to move an object in "X" and "Y" direction

Tags: android, math, canvas, geometry

I am working on android studio and I want to create the effect of throwing an object, in this case a circle drawn on the canvas. But I'm having problems. Can someone guide me?

I take the "X" and the "Y" value where the user touch but how can i make that the circle move in that direction?

Thanks

Game class:

```
public class Game extends SurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener  {

Paint paint;
int x, y, radius = 100, speedX = 5, speedY = 5, touchY, touchX;
boolean move = false;
boolean one_time = true;

public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);

    paint = new Paint();
}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawRect(0,0,canvas.getWidth(),canvas.getHeight(),paint);

    if (one_time == true){
        x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
        y = canvas.getHeight()/2;
        one_time = false;
    }

    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

    if (move == true){

        if (x >= canvas.getWidth() - radius) {
            speedX = -5;
        }

        if (x <= radius) {
            speedX = 5;
        }

        if (y >= canvas.getHeight() - radius) {
            speedY = -5;
        }

        if (y <= radius) {
            speedY = 5;
        }

        x = x + speedX;
        y = y + speedY;
    }

    invalidate();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):

            touchX = (int) motionEvent.getX();
            touchY = (int) motionEvent.getY();

            move = true;

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Is your question regarding the math or regarding the implementation?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes what i want is the math that allow me to know where the user touch and move the ball in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna need to be an `x+=speedX` or `y+=speedY`  in there somewhere so that the x or y value changes causing the ball to move. If your trying to implement some physics in there ur gonna need some maths.

Comment: Note that the OP is already doing this calculation: `x = x + speedX;`. For your answer to be complete, you need to explain why the OP's code doesn't work and specifically how to change it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Yes what i want is the math that allow me to know where the user touch and move the ball in that direction

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to change the (x, y) values at a certain interval. You can do this with the `Timer` class, but then you get into some difficult multithreading code. I suggest looking at using OpenGL ES or a higher level library such as LibGDX. Both of these provide an event loop which allow you to update objects that will be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to move the circle to the place the user touched the screen, using some type of constant speed?

If all you want is to move a circle the Timer can do it - or you could use something like: https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/FPSAnimator

Finally, are you always looking for a linear straight line constant speed movement? Then your math is fine. If your looking for something with gravity etc. then you can reference this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/physics-based-animation.html and consider this: https://github.com/google/liquidfun

Answer (score 0):

This will move the circle exactly to the point the user touched:

```
theta = atan2(touchY - y,touchX - x)
speedX = cos(theta)
speedY = sin(theta)
x += speedX
y += speedY
```

What happens once the circle reaches the point depends on how the calculation is implemented. If you want the circle to continue on its path and travel the direction infinitely, you must only calculate the velocity of x and y once. That way the same x and y velocity will always be used to update the position of the circle.

If the velocities are recalculated every time the position of the circle is to be updated, the circle will continuously move to the point even once it has technically reached it and must manually be stopped.

The velocities can be increased by multiplying them by a value greater than 1. To maintain the correct direction, the value should be the same for both velocities.

Example:

```
theta = atan2(touchY - y,touchX - x)
speedX = maxSpeed*cos(theta)
speedY = maxSpeed*sin(theta)
x += speedX
y += speedY
```